Self-contained fictional narrative consisting of only about 150 words, and without conflict between the characters
The title describes the goal.  Below is one attempt to achieve the goal.
My question: Can I say that there's no conflict between the characters, or is that just my opinion?
There's an obvious possibility that I am biased, because I intended to write a story without conflict between the characters.  How do I know whether or not I succeeded?
The Picture of Dorian Abel
Cain Abel was a painter. One day, Cain’s brother Dorian Abel asked, “Could you paint a picture of my face?”
Soon, a stunning portrait of Dorian Abel was completed, and neighbors gathered to admire it. Dorian Abel became jealous (of Cain, not of the painting), and said that the painting was a waste of a good, blank canvas. Cain Abel was disappointed, but believed his brother was sincere.
“I know that you were bored sitting still and waiting for me to finish the painting,” said Cain Abel. “I wasted some of your time, some small (but real) part of your life. I apologize.”
Dorian Abel said, “I accept your apology.” Then Dorian Abel whitewashed the canvas, and in that moment Dorian Abel forgot how the portrait looked. Dorian Abel remembered his own silent opinion that the portrait had been excellent, but could  never again remember anything else about the portrait.

This site is not for writing critiques; that is why I voted to close.

@Amadeus I could edit to remove all of the story, except for character D experiencing an internal feeling of jealousy of character C.  The question   could then be largely about the tag "conflict" and could ask whether an individual character's jealousy is (always or usually?) an example of conflict, and in particular an example of internal conflict.

For convenience, the "conflict" tag for questions is described as follows ... Conflict is a concept from narrative fiction. It refers to either the ambivalent emotions of the hero ("inner conflict") or the opposition by antagonistic forces that the hero encounters. In a group of heroes, the "inner conflict" may be disagreement between group members. An example for "inner conflict" is Gandalf being torn over whether he should use or destroy the ring. Group inner conflict happens when Boromir attacks Frodo. The Nazgul are antagonists.

In your story, one character is jealous of the other. Jealousy is an internal conflict: Someone wants something they don't have.
Because of his jealousy, the character makes a disparaging remark, creating an affective interpersonal conflict between him and his brother.

"Jealousy is an internal conflict"  I agree that something about the situation makes Dorian Abel feel not completely satisfied.  Why do you call that feeling a "conflict"?  Is there some other feeling within Dorian Abel that his jealousy is in conflict with?  In an alternative scenario, Dorian Abel might be puzzled about the reaction of the neighbors.  In that alternative scenario, Dorian Abel might be satisfied that the portrait is good enough, but not be particularly impressed with it.  Would that also be an example of  "internal conflict"?

@RenEhDaycart A conflict is a mismatch of goals. Dorian Abel feels jealousy because he too would like to paint as well as his brother. That is his goal. But an opposing force or antagonist, his lack of talent, keeps him from this goal. You might say that Dorian's lack of talent has the goal that Dorian remains a bad painter. Dorian and his lack of talent are in conflict with each other. That is the root of jealousy: a conflict between what you cannot have (one goal) and what you are forced to accept (an opposing goal).
